# Is there any difference between these two constructors for a node in a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

Comparing the following two portions of code, is there any difference between these two constructors for a node in a linked list?  Specifically consider the constructor with a single E object as the parameter.

**A.**

```
public class Listnode<E> {
  //*** fields ***
    private E data;
    private Listnode<E> next;

  //*** constructors ***
    // 2 constructors
    public Listnode(E d) {
        this(d, null);
    }

    public Listnode(E d, Listnode n) {
        data = d;
        next = n;
    }
}
```

**B.**

```
public class Listnode<E> {
  //*** fields ***
    private E data;
    private Listnode<E> next;

  //*** constructors ***
    // 2 constructors
    public Listnode(E d) {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }

    public Listnode(E d, Listnode n) {
        data = d;
        next = n;
    }
}
```

I'm just starting to teach myself Java with the help of the Internet, and I thought the implementation in **B** was easier to read, however **A** came from a reliable source.  On the surface they both seem to work fine.  Is there any advantage of one over the other?

Comment: The first code `A` is using good practice reusing code, that would decreases maintenance points.  There is no practical difference from each other!

Comment: Note that the first version, which is preferred, is called *constructor chaining*.

Answer (score 3):

The end result is the same assignments for both constructors however, Option A is better because you don't duplicate code.

Option B is more error prone because you assign the fields in both constructors.

This can lead to potential mistakes if you mess up an assignment in one of the constructors or forget to assign one of the fields.  Also if you later add more fields to the class, you will have to remember to assign values to them in multiple places.

Also if you had to do input validation, you would have to duplicate that in multiple constructors (or at least call validation methods in multiple constructors)  it's better to have all the validation in one place.

For example, let's say you need to make sure the data isn't `null`:

```
//validate that data can't be null
public Listnode(E d) {
    if(d ==null){
       throw new NullPointerException("data can't be null");
    }
    data = d;
    next = null;
}

public Listnode(E d, Listnode n) {
    if(d ==null){
       throw new NullPointerException("data can't be null");
    }
    data = d;
    next = n;
}
```

This all violates the Don't Repeat Yourself principle (DRY)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  Thank you!

Comment: The validation argument is a perfect point although OP being fairly new I would add an example. It would make your answer even better! +1 anyway